# Sqlite database is corrupted after copy on some devices android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new in android development and this is my first app with a database. I created a database with DB Browser for SQlite under Ubuntu.

It seems that the problem is present on Android devices below marhmallow but i'm not completely sure.

here ther's my code to copy database:

```
//version number.
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.sqlite";
private static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public DBHelper(Context context ) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}


/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean bCopyOk = false;
    try{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>-1) myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        bCopyOk = true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (bCopyOk) Log.v(TAG, "[copyDataBase] - Database copied OK!");
    }
}
```

With all devices with Android Nougat (7.0.x) all works fine but, if i test this app on another version of android, i find this error log:

```
03-22 20:08:21.660 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
03-22 20:08:21.661 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31278: (2) open(/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/db.sqlite) - 
03-22 20:08:21.661 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/db.sqlite'.
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:845)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:830)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:723)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:690)
                                                                                 at com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi.DBHelper.openDataBase(DBHelper.java:154)
                                                                                 at com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6304)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-22 20:08:21.662 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi W/SQLiteDatabase: Retry to open database[/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/db.sqlite] due to error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
03-22 20:08:21.662 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
03-22 20:08:21.662 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31278: (2) open(/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/db.sqlite) - 
03-22 20:08:21.663 9010-9010/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi/databases/db.sqlite'.
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:845)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:830)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:732)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:690)
                                                                                 at com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi.DBHelper.openDataBase(DBHelper.java:154)
                                                                                 at com.andrea.risuscito_passaggi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:94)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6304)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've searched a lot but i don't find any solution. Thanks

EDIT:
I stopped looking for the error only in java code and I began to look into the database code. I found two errors:

1. the folder to the empty database was not created, so I added this code before copy database

   `// check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
               File databaseFile = new File( DATABASE_PATH);
               if (!databaseFile.exists()){
                   databaseFile.mkdir();
               }`
2. there was a view in the database that was clobbered, I could not fix it but I solved by writing the query from java

Comment: What happens if your create a database on the android device and transfer that to another device rather than using a database created by external source?

Comment: @MarkKeen I have not tried. I should create a database with an Android app and then put it in the folder assets, or write a creation script in my app?

Comment: Create a local sqlite database on the phone i.e. just create a test app that has a button to generate a sqlite db, and a button to read a sqlite database from its database directory (when clicked have a toast if database exists and is read correctly)  - you can then use adb to pull the db to your desktop from the phone. Install your test app on a problem phone, push the file to` /data/data/[com.whatever]/databases`, open your test app and click 'read' button - if you see you toast then you know there is some incompatibility between DB Browser and some versions of SQLite for Android.

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks, tomorrow I will try

Comment: @MarkKeen I tried what you said and it did not work. I stopped looking for the error only in java code and I began to look into the database code.

I found two errors:

1. the folder to the empty database was not created, so I added this code 
`// check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
            File databaseFile = new File( DATABASE_PATH);
            if (!databaseFile.exists()){
                databaseFile.mkdir();
            }`
2. there was a view in the database that was clobbered, I could not fix it but I solved by writing the query from java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stopped looking for the error only in java code and I began to look into the database code. I found two errors:

1.the folder to the empty database was not created, so I added this code before copy database

```
// check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
            File databaseFile = new File( DATABASE_PATH);
            if (!databaseFile.exists()){
                databaseFile.mkdir();
            }
```

2. there was a view in the database that was clobbered, I could not fix it but I solved by writing the query from java